# Source for Web Service in SharePoint

Tags: web-services, xml

Is it possible to use XML data as input for SharePoint web service? If possible how to implement that? Can we use input as Objects other than XML data ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use XML as input data,

[The Power of XmlElement Parameters in ASP.NET Web Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480498.aspx)

[What is the best way to send xml data to a web service rather than using CDATA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517741/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-xml-data-to-a-web-service-rather-than-using-cdata)